# Highlight a Featured Post?

Tags: posts, sticky-post

I would like to "highlight" a featured post above all other posts with a special indicator.

Is there a feature in WordPress that will do this or do I need to install a third party plug-in?

I am using a custom WordPress install (not WP hosted).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the "sticky" feature.

In the "Page Attributes" metabox (labelled as **Publish**), if you click the "edit" link next to the **Visibility** option, there is a checkbox which allows you to *"Stick this post to the front page"*.

Unless a theme overrides the default query, that post will show up above all the others. In addition, it adds the class name "sticky" to the attributes returned by `post_class()`, so you can style it however you want.

[image]

To add some text to your featured posts and highlight them, add a function like this inside the loop in your index.php (or loop.php, etc., depending on your theme):

```
if (is_sticky($post->ID)) echo '<span class="featured">Featured!</span>';
```

You can do the same thing with the css :before property, like this:

```
div.sticky h2:before {
     content: "Featured! ";
}
```

(assuming you're using h2's to display the titles of your posts, and you want to add the text before the title)

Comment: Wow. Great response and I dig the screenshot too! 

That's great about the "sticky" class, but is there anyway to insert plain-text (such as the words "Featured") into an HTML element?

Comment: You could do that in your template files. I'm editing my answer to cover that.