# Is there a way to Insert a post to post list?

Tags: hooks

In some websites or blogs (and mine too) they often have a list of their recent posts on their home page or top page. My idea is I'd like to insert one or some great posts that I'd like to highlight to the visitors naturally to the array and then render. What PHP file should I look to and what hooks or functions can I use for it? Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! I'm afraid there is no one specific/best way to do this. It highly depends on your setup. [There is a concept of sticky posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/highlight-a-featured-post) in WP to solve this, but it is up to each theme and plugin to follow that or implement the feature differently

Comment: You could use the recent posts or a query block if you're using the block editor. You could have a featured posts tag or category for picking which posts should appear. You'd do this via the block editor or the site editor, no PHP necessary